# If one series converge, the other also converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converge, then

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sqrt[4]{a_{n}^{5}}=\underset{n=1}{\overset{\infty}{\sum}}a_{n}^{\frac{5}{4}}$ converge?

Please verify answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Because $\sum a_n$ converges, we know that the limit $\lim a_n = 0$, by the Divergence Test.

This means that $\exists N, \forall n > N, a_n <1 $.  It stands to reason then that $a_n^{5/4} \le a_n$ for all such $n>N$.  By Direct Comparison, then, $\sum a_n^{5/4}$ also converges.

We cannot say $\sum a_n^{5/4} < \sum a_n$. Someone said that but it is untrue.  It all depends on the front-end behavior.  If for the first $N$ terms $a_n^{5/4}$ is sufficiently larger than $a_n$ then the inequality of the actual sum may be reversed.

---

It doesnt matter if for any terms $a_n<0$.  If a term is odd then $a_n^5$ is still odd. And the principle fourth root $a_n^{5/4}$ is going to be a complex number where $a_n^{5/4} = |a_n|^{5/4} \frac{\sqrt{2}+i\sqrt{2}}{2}$ for all negative $a_n$

The principle fourth root $a_n^{5/4}$ for positive $a_n$ is still positive and real.

Simply break the series apart into two separate series of positive and negative $a_n$ terms.  We know that $\sum_{a_n>0} a_n^{5/4}$ is going to converge as per the first part of this proof. It has fewer terms and therefore converges to a smaller sum.

For the series $\sum_{a_n<0} a_n^{5/4}$ we get the final sum $\frac{\sqrt{2}+i\sqrt{2}}{2} \sum_{a_n<0} |a_n|^{5/4} $. Notice the sum is still going to  be convergent as per the first part of this proof, but there is a complex scalar that was factored out.

Thus, even for a series containing negative $a_n$ terms, the sum $\sum a_n^{5/4}$ is simply going to be the sum $\left(\sum_{a_n>0} a_n^{5/4}\right) + \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}+i\sqrt{2}}{2} \sum_{a_n<0} |a_n|^{5/4}\right) $

Each individual series is now a series of positive terms, each containing fewer terms than the original series and therefore each converges to a smaller sum.

---

**Disclaimer** Im no expert in infinite series. They are not exactly intuitive.

The problem is infinitely more complicated if you let $a_n$ take any complex value.

Answer (score 0):

Because $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ converge, then $a_n\rightarrow0$, so for big $n$:  $a_{n}<1$, which implies $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}^{\frac{5}{4}}<\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}$$ so it's also converge

Comment: Maybe ${a_n}\geqslant{0}$ ?

Comment: Do we know that the $a_n$ are nonnegative? Otherwise something like $a_n=(-1)^n/n$ can cause problems...

Comment: because he need $\sqrt[4]{*}$,so i think it implies $a_n \geq 0$

Comment: @Tai: Since it is a question of convergence, not a question of showing the series converges, I don't think we can assume $a_n\geq0$.

Comment: Supposing of course non-negative terms, the last inequality isn't true in general, while the conclusioin remains true. Take for example, $a_n=(100,\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{9},...\frac{1}{n^2}...)$.

Comment: Im wondering if it really matters though if $a_n \ge 0$. If the first sum converges then the limit of the terms is zero, less than 1. So the modulus of any complex value is going to be less than 1 as well, with a limit of zero still.

Comment: The inequality in the final sum is also incorrect.